# Regex to pick out url part of a long string

Tags: c#, regex

I have a very long string, somewhere in this string, there is an url. In this example this url is at the beginning.

```
"http://localhost:1234/api/$metadata#this_entry_is_variable_and_can_exist_of_numbers_and_characters/$entity","Version":"AAAEEEIIU=""
```

I'm trying to write a RegEx in C# for this particular string, to extract the url after the following rules:

1. The url always starts with http:// or https://
2. After the url, the port is sometimes specified, not always
3. After the port, there is a path, in this example `/api`, but it can be any characters
4. After the path, in this example `/api`, it is always `/$metadata`
5. After the `/$metadata` there is a hashtag `#` followed by a string of any characters
6. The last part of the url always ends with `/$entity`

This is the RegEx I have come up with so far:

```
(^http://\w+(\.\w+)*(:[0-9]+)?\/?(\/[.\^$metadata$(\#(\[a-zA-Z0-9)(\$(\entity$))]*).*?)
```

When testing this in LinqPad, the following issues occur:

1. If the string contains more than the url, there is no match
2. It does not strictly validate on /$metadata, it accepts /$metadata1111
3. It does not strictly validate on /$entity, it accepts /$entity111
4. Obviously it does not accept https:// yet.

Can anyone give me a hint on were to continue, as I'm stuck..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex doesn't follow a Regular Expression constructing rules hence no expected match. This is what you are expressing:

```
https?://[^/]+/[^/]+/\$metadata#[^/]+/\$entity
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/4URxaU/1)

Comment: Wow, the was fast! Thanks!

Comment: @revo: just a minor amendment: the regex should probably be ended with `\b` to avoid [such cases](https://regex101.com/r/4URxaU/2)

Comment: That's the point but it's not obvious how an URL ending can be specified within the input string. @DmitryEgorov

Answer (score 2):

Try this regex:

```
https?://[\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*(?::\d+)?/.*?\$metadata#.*?\$entity\b
```

[Demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=https%3f%3a%2f%2f%5b%5cw-%5d%2b%28%3f%3a%5c.%5b%5cw-%5d%2b%29*%28%3f%3a%3a%5cd%2b%29%3f%2f.*%3f%5c%24metadata%23.*%3f%5c%24entity%5cb&i=http%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a1234%2fapi%2f%24metadata%23this_entry_is_variable_and_can_exist_of_numbers_and_characters%2f%24entity%0d%0ahttps%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a1234%2fapi%2f%24metadata%23this_entry_is_variable_and_can_exist_of_numbers_and_characters%2f%24entity%0d%0ahttps%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a1234%2fapi%2f%24metadata111%23this_entry_is_variable_and_can_exist_of_numbers_and_characters%2f%24entity%0d%0ahttps%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a1234%2fapi%2f%24metadata%23this_entry_is_variable_and_can_exist_of_numbers_and_characters%2f%24entity111)

To you questions:

1. You matched only one regex because of the `^`. It matches only the start of input string if `RegexOptions.Multiline` is not set, and also start of every new line (after newline chars) if `RegexOptions.Multiline` is set.
2. The regex gets mixed up in the part where `$metadata...entity$` is surrounded by `[]`
3. See 2.
4. Simply make the `s` optional with `?`

Comment: Thanks for the answer and detailed explanation. Much appreciated!

Comment: There is no need to include matching TLD part or port when these are not a must. Also it accepts `/$metadata1111` which it shouldn't.

Comment: @revo: yes, you're right. And this is exactly what you've done as far as I can see. So I've upvoted your answer and kept mine just to retain answers to the OP questions